# Why does my HTC Desire browser crash on startup after update?

Tags: updates, browser, htc-desire, crashes

after I've applied [recent OTA update](http://androidcommunity.com/htc-desire-2-29-405-2-update-available-now-20101206/) (2.29.405.2) to my HTC Desire I can't use built-in browser anymore. It crashes every time I run it. Here is a stacktrace:

> 12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeEnableGifAnimation
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.webkit.HTCWebCore.nativeEnableGifAnimation(Native Method)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.webkit.WebView.fnEnableGifAnimation(WebView.java:13341)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.webkit.WebSettings.setIsEnableGifAnimation(WebSettings.java:1617)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at com.android.browser.BrowserSettings$Observer.update(BrowserSettings.java:335)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at com.android.browser.TabControl.createNewWebView(TabControl.java:707)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at com.android.browser.TabControl.createNewTab(TabControl.java:180)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at com.android.browser.BrowserActivity.onCreate(BrowserActivity.java:430)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   12-08 20:13:45.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2147):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92): Error running process
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/system/xbin/procrank] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=11, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, ANDROID_DATA=/data, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.framework.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.android.pimlib.jar:/system/framework/com.htc.android.easopen.jar:/system/framework/com.scalado.util.ScaladoUtil.jar, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=10,65536, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib]
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:226)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:201)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.logProcessResult(ActivityManagerService.java:9437)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$900(ActivityManagerService.java:155)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$9.run(ActivityManagerService.java:9614)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:224)
>   12-08 20:13:48.398: ERROR/ActivityManager(92):     ... 4 more

I have tried factory reset, but that doesn't help. Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O.K. I've resolved the issue by re-applying the OTA update from sdcard with recovery mode.

Comment: @AI Everett Will do, the site says that I only can do that after 20 hours :)